# Invoke an intelliJ run/debug configuration from command line?

Tags: intellij-idea, background-process, jetbrains-ide

I've got some Run/Debug Configurations defined in my JetBrains IDE, and to run them obviously you'd normally press the green 'play' icon;

[image: run/debug configuration]

However, I want to combine that with scripts I've got on my machine which detect file system changes and re-run some validation steps in the background;

[image: cargo watch]

Now what I'd like to do is to say something like 'when the CLI detects that something is stale, start the run/debug configuration in the IDE'.

So in pseudo-bash, something like

```
# if any "*.rs" file changes, press the green button in intellij;
watch-files *.rs -x "run-intellij-config 'check controlplane'
```

Is it possible to invoke tasks within IntelliJ like this?

Comment: Seems like there is no way to do that. Feel free to raise a new feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this currently, please vote for [IDEA-157076](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157076/Start-a-run-configuration-from-the-CLI) to be notified on any progress with this feature request